# Get weeks from date range

Tags: javascript

I need to extract the weeks based on the given date range.

Below is my code which will return NO of weeks

```
WeekByDates() {
    let stDate = moment((dates[0].value)).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); //2018-06-01
    let eDate = moment((dates[1].value)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');//2018-06-14

    let startDate = moment(stDate);
    let endDate = moment(eDate);
    let weekData = [];

    while (startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
      if (weekData.length > 0) {
        // Update end date
        let lastObj = weekData[weekData.length - 1];
        lastObj['endDate'] = moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        lastObj['label'] = `${moment(lastObj.startDate).format('MM/DD')} - ${moment(lastObj['endDate']).format('MM/DD')}`
        startDate.add(1, 'days');
      }
      weekData.push({ startDate: moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') });
      startDate.add(6, 'days');
    }
      if (startDate.isAfter(endDate)) {
      // Update last object
      let lastObj = weekData[weekData.length - 1];
      lastObj['endDate'] = moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      lastObj['label'] = `${moment(lastObj.startDate).format('MM/DD')} - ${moment(lastObj['endDate']).format('MM/DD')}`
    }                                                     
    console.log(weekData)
    return weekData;
  }
```

Expected Weeks should be

```
06/01 - 06/07
06/08 - 06/14
```

But actually it returns

```
06/01 - 06/07
06/08 - 06/14
06/15 - 06/14
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here. Please help

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? Just count the number of weeks (2) or return a breakup (2018-06-01 to 07, 2018-06-08 to 14)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to check when push to array also `if (moment(startDate).isSameOrBefore(endDate))`

```js
function WeekByDates() {
    let stDate = moment('2018-06-01').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let eDate = moment('2018-06-14').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    let startDate = moment(stDate);
    let endDate = moment(eDate);
    let weekData = [];

    while (startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
      if (weekData.length > 0) {
        // Update end date
        let lastObj = weekData[weekData.length - 1];
        lastObj['endDate'] = moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        lastObj['label'] = `${moment(lastObj.startDate).format('MM/DD')} - ${moment(lastObj['endDate']).format('MM/DD')}`
        startDate.add(1, 'days');
      }
      if (moment(startDate).isSameOrBefore(endDate))
      weekData.push({ startDate: moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') });
      startDate.add(6, 'days');
    }
      if (startDate.isAfter(endDate)) {
      // Update last object
      let lastObj = weekData[weekData.length - 1];
      lastObj['endDate'] = moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      lastObj['label'] = `${moment(lastObj.startDate).format('MM/DD')} - ${moment(lastObj.endDate).format('MM/DD')}`
    }                                                     
    console.log(weekData)
    return weekData;
  }
  
  WeekByDates();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following check before pushing the value to `weekdata` as well

```
while (startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
  if (weekData.length > 0) {
    // Update end date
    let lastObj = weekData[weekData.length - 1];
    lastObj['endDate'] = moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    lastObj['label'] = `${moment(lastObj.startDate).format('MM/DD')} - ${moment(lastObj['endDate']).format('MM/DD')}`
    startDate.add(1, 'days');
  }
  if (startDate.isAfter(endDate)) { //check before pushing
    weekData.push({ startDate: moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') });
    startDate.add(6, 'days');
  }
}
```